# MYSQL order by + group by... fastest way?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, inner-join

I am trying to optimize a SQL query and I would like some expert opinion on the best/fastest way to combine GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Basically I am trying to select the lowest price from a products table and group them by merchant name.

This was my original query:

`select p.*, m.*, d.* from datafeeds as d, products as p left outer join meta as m on p.mykey = m.mykey where p.datafeed_id = d.id and (match(p.name) against ('+asics +"gel" -women*' in boolean mode)) and p.datafeed_id = '35' and p.is_custom = 0 group by d.merchant_name order by d.merchant_name limit 50`

And the ORDER BY was not working, I was getting grouped products but not the ones with the lowest prices.

After reading other discussions i came up with an improved query:

```
SELECT p . * , m . * , d . * 
FROM datafeeds AS d, products AS p
INNER JOIN (

SELECT MIN( display_price ) AS MinPrice
FROM products AS p
WHERE 1 =1
AND (

MATCH (
p.name
)
AGAINST (
'+asics +"gel" -women*'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
)
)
AND p.datafeed_id =  '35'
AND p.is_custom =0
GROUP BY merchant_name
) AS p2 ON p.display_price = p2.MinPrice
LEFT OUTER JOIN meta AS m ON p.mykey = m.mykey
WHERE p.datafeed_id = d.id
AND (

MATCH (
p.name
)
AGAINST (
'+asics +"gel" -women*'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
)
)
AND p.datafeed_id =  '35'
AND p.is_custom =0
GROUP BY d.merchant_name
ORDER BY d.merchant_name
LIMIT 50`
```

The query gets the correct results but it is quite slow.
Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
SELECT          p.*, 
                m.*, 
                d.* 
FROM            datafeeds AS d, 
                ( 
                         SELECT   * 
                         FROM     products 
                         WHERE    1 = 1 
                         AND      ( 
                                           MATCH ( name ) against ( '+asics +"gel" -women*' IN boolean mode ) ) 
                         AND      datafeed_id = '35' 
                         AND      is_custom =0 
                         ORDER BY merchant_name, 
                                  display_price) AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN meta                             AS m 
ON              p.mykey = m.mykey 
WHERE           p.datafeed_id = d.id 
GROUP BY        d.merchant_name 
ORDER BY        d.merchant_name 
LIMIT           50
```

Comment: thank you Trung... the speed is more or less the same but the SQL looks a lot cleaner

Comment: How many record do you have in table products? If you only execute the sub query be aliased as p - (....) AS p, is it fast or slow?

Comment: around 300.000 records... your query took 0.0536 seconds to run... and the one i posted above 0.0593

Comment: Could you try to execute this query "SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY        merchant_name ORDER BY  merchant_name LIMIT 50"? How long does it take?

Comment: Query took 1.5772 sec

Comment: Seem it takes more than a minute for a simple query. I think you could create an index on *merchant_name* column of table *products* to speed up the query.

Comment: It took 1.5772 sec... 1 and half Seconds... not minutes... quite slow anyway.... i will experiment with index... thanks again

Comment: Is there any improvement when using index, Giulio?

Comment: i turns out that merchant_name was already indexed.... at the moment i am using your query plus some query caching and it seems to be working fine